# Excel COUNTIF() function won't accept a formula as range

Tags: excel, countif

The command I am trying to execute is:

`=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A2023,MONTH(C2:C2023)=9)), $E2)`

I would like to simply check if E2 exists in the list.

`UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A2023,MONTH(C2:C2023)=9))` works fine, returning a list of numbers. However, wrapping it in the `COUNTIF()` makes excel tell me there is a problem with the formula. Alternatively, if there is another approach to checking if the element exists in the list, that would also work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with Unique you would get 1 or 0 as your output, correct?

Comment: No, Filter() provides a list of numbers, i.e. 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, and Unique() converts that to 1, 2, 3, 4. I suppose the Unique() is not strictly necessary to accomplish what I want, although I think it may speed the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIF will not take an array as a range.  Just add the other criterion to the FILTER and check if there is a return:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(@FILTER(A2:A2023,(MONTH(C2:C2023)=9)*(A2:A2023=$E2))))
```

Or

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($E2,FILTER(A2:A2023,MONTH(C2:C2023)=9),0))
```

If you want a `1` or `0` response simply add `--` to the formula: `=--NOT(...` or `=--ISNUMBER(...`

Comment: I should have thought of that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIF` seems to need a pure cell reference in the first argument.  You could put your `UNIQUE` formula in one cell (F2 for example) and then put `=COUNTIF(F2#, $E2)` in another.  This Assumes you have Excel Office 365 that supports Dynamic Arrays.